# Creating savepoint and rollingback in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

How to create a savepoint and how to use rollback if exception occurs  in hibernate I know how it works in jdbc but i got stuck creating savepoint in hibernate program.

My program is 'public class StudentStoredData {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

```
String name = " ";
int count = 0;
int cond = 0;
// creating configuration object
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("Student.cfg.xml");// populates the data of the configuration file


SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

try {
  do {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter 1 to insert and 0 to quit");
    cond = scn.nextInt();
    if (cond == 0)
      break;
    Student e1 = new Student();

    System.out.println("Enter Id ");
    int id = scn.nextInt();
    e1.setId(id);
    System.out.println("Enter name ");
    name = scn.next();
    e1.setName(name);

    session.persist(e1);// persisting the object
    System.out.println("successfully saved");

      t.commit();

  } while (cond != 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("error occured in saving values . rolling back the recent changes");
  } finally {
  session.close();
}
```

}
}
'
Their is student class with id and name as attribute and setter and getter method as persistent class. Where do i get the connection variable .. I am new to hibernate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementing savepoint, you need to implement Work interface. In the implementation , you would do your custom tasks like updating database etc.

```
Work work = new Work() {
    public void execute(Connection arg0) throws SQLException {
             //custom task
    }
};
```

The call

> session.doWork(work)

And if there is any exxception just call

> connection.rollback(work)

Answer (score 0):

```
Savepoint savepoint = null;

try{

   person.setPersonName("John");
   session.update(person);
   session.flush();
   savepoint = setSavepoint("savepoint_1");

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Exception occured rolling back to save point");
    rollbackSavepoint(savepoint);
}

private Savepoint savepoint;
public Savepoint setSavepoint(final String savePoint) {
    session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException      {
            savepoint = connection.setSavepoint(savePoint);
      }
    });
  return savepoint;
}

public void rollbackSavepoint(final Savepoint savepoint) {
    session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException     {
        connection.rollback(savepoint);
    }
  });
}
```