# Hibernate executeUpdate is successful but list operation does not reflect changes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am following a simple Hibernate tutorial on the Internet. It seemed like executeUpdate was successful (the row count returned was 1). However, when I called list(), it returned me old result. Is this the expected behaviour of hibernate? Is there anyway that I can get the updated data in the same transaction?

This is my source code:

```
//Prep work
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    //Get All Employees
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
    List<Employee> empList = query.list();
    for(Employee emp : empList){
        System.out.println("List of Employees::"+emp.getId()+","+emp.getAddress().getCity());
    }
    //Update Employee
    query = session.createQuery("update Employee set name= :name where id= :id");
    query.setParameter("name", "Pankaj Kumar");
    query.setLong("id", 1);
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Employee Update Status="+result);


    query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
    empList = query.list();
    for(Employee emp : empList){
        System.out.println("List of Employees::"+emp.getId()+","+emp.getAddress().getCity());
    }

    //rolling back to save the test data
    tx.rollback();

    //closing hibernate resources
    sessionFactory.close();
```

The result was returned:

```
List of Employees::1,San Jose
List of Employees::2,Santa Clara
List of Employees::3,Bangalore
List of Employees::4,New Delhi
Hibernate: update EMPLOYEE set emp_name=? where emp_id=?
Employee Update Status=1
Hibernate: select employee0_.emp_id as emp_id1_1_, employee0_.emp_name as emp_name2_1_, employee0_.emp_salary as emp_sala3_1_ from EMPLOYEE employee0_
List of Employees::1,San Jose
List of Employees::2,Santa Clara
List of Employees::3,Bangalore
List of Employees::4,New Delhi
```

Answer (score 0):

You are performing the same query again, but you never committed the first transacation, hence the changes you made were never persisted.  To remedy this, you can try committing your Hibernate transaction:

```
tx.commit();
```

The pattern you should be using looks something like this:

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
List<Employee> empList = query.list();
// update, insert, etc.
tx.commit();
```

Note that this should taking place in a try-catch block, and should an exception occur you would have the chance to rollback the entire transaction.

Comment: and what to do to rollback the transaction even with an successful update?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen why you use `tx.commit();` after the select, i thought it should be after the update?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I don't see this requirement when I read the OP.  Can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: in his code he got this: `//rolling back to save the test data
    tx.rollback();` this lets me think that he always wants to restore the test data after running the test

Comment: Yes, but this conflicts with being able to "see" the data in his database.  Either the update is committed or it's not, you can't have it both ways.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Actually writing to the database is no longer a unit test, it's an integration test, and yes the OP should probably be using some sort of framework here.  The immediate answer to the question is that the transaction was never committed, hence not visible during the subsequent query.

Comment: Yes, I am writing some tests so I need a way to roll back all the update operations. I also need access to the updated data in the same transaction to confirm that my update has been successful

Comment: @skynova2070 I don't think this is the correct way to approach this.  If you want to test writing data to a table, then do the write and then use a script to cleanup afterwards.  Rollbacks are a very specific thing intended to be used when something goes wrong halfway through an update, insert, etc.  If your updates are successful, then consider using `DELETE` in a cleanup script to remove your test data.

Comment: Yeah, i guess it is the only way

Answer (score 0):

Changes are actually saved to DB after the transaction is committed, that is the whole point of transaction.

If you are facing a scenario where you need to update data on database then get it for further processing either you update it locally on your objects which will be residing in the persistence context ( in that case will make much more sence to do createOrUpdate instead of your query), or separate the two steps in 2 transactions

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for testing your `update` to DB and `rollback` once the update is success. If so, you have to have the `savePoint` within your transaction. This post [Creating savepoint and rollingback in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871867/creating-savepoint-and-rollingback-in-hibernate) might be helpful.